# Problema em dá o build no projeto Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Quando eu tento copilar gera esse erro;

```
       main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.algaworks.cobranca.CobrancaApplication.main(CobrancaApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

2016-01-10 14:58:38.980 ERROR 7172 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.algaworks.cobranca.CobrancaApplication.main(CobrancaApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2016-01-10 14:58:38.993  INFO 7172 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-01-10 14:58:39.022 ERROR 7172 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.algaworks.cobranca.CobrancaApplication.main(CobrancaApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2016-01-10 14:58:39.034  INFO 7172 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/mary/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/cobranca/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.13/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.13/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.7/aspectjweaver-1.8.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.30/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.2.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.2.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.13/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.3.1/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.3.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.4/groovy-2.4.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.2.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.4/jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.4/jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.4/jackson-core-2.6.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/mary/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar]
```

**Porque gera esse erro?**

Ver se consegue encontrar o processo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso indica que um mesmo **processo** do `Spring Boot` ou algum outro *servidor de aplicação* por exemplo pode estar aberto utilizando o endereço `IP:Porta` que foi setado, não é possivel utilizar o mesmo endereço de **ip** e **porta** ao mesmo tempo.

Verifique se não há alguma **instancia** aberta rodando, caso encontrar, feche e tente novamente.

Nesse caso, procure pelo processo utilizando a porta `8080`.

Comment: Como faço para encontrar esse processo? porque não existe nenhum servidor utilizando essa porta pelo que eu sei.

Comment: Você utiliza Windows, Linux ou MacOSX?

Comment: windows, mas se eu não encontra o processo eu poderia simplesmente mudar o numero da porta do Tomcat né?

Comment: Sim, poderia. No Windows direto pelo command prompt, pode digitar netstat -b -a que será listado os processos com as portas, outra forma é utilizar o monitor de recursos do próprio windows ou software de terceiro como TCPView ou Process Hacker.

Comment: atualizei minha postagem, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Aonde que eu mudo o numero da porta?

Comment: Aparentemente é um processo do MySQL, a porta padrão do mysql é 3306, tente fazer a alteração.

Comment: Aonde que eu mudo o numero da porta?

Comment: Você está pedindo para mim fazer isso porque você observou na foto do cmd - MSDOS que é o mysql que está usando a porta 8080?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo, porém aparentemente olhei errado. Na verdade é o processo tnslsnr.exe que esta utilizando a porta 8080, vou remover meu comment anterior.

Comment: É um processo do Oracle que esta utilizando a porta, da uma olhada aqui para entender como alterar, caso desejar. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14207/ports.htm

Comment: acabei de parar o serviço do banco de dados oracle, que droga, é impressionante saber que o banco utiliza essa porta, porque não fui eu que coloquei o oracle para utilizar a porta. mas eu parei o serviço do oracle e funcionou, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra solução é mudar a porta que a aplicação spring boot vai utilizar.

Para isso basta informar a porta desejada no application.properties.

...\src\main\resources\application.properties

```
server.port=9080
```